# Google App Engine with Struts2 Error Caused by com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder

Tags: java, google-app-engine, struts2, classnotfoundexception

Trying to deploy a `Struts2` app on `Google App Engine` and running into an exception.

My issue seems to be similar to but different from the issue [described here](https://struts.apache.org/docs/google-app-engine-gae.html).

1. I am using a `ServletContextListener` to disable the `OgnlRuntime` security manager
2. I have include `velocity-tools-1.4.jar` with the deployment
3. The app runs with no issues in my local instance. The error occurs when deployed.

My stack trace is as follows and would be very appreciative of any suggestions or insights into a work around.

```
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@de973f{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~appname/1.386434995212162889}
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException - Class: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4
File: ContainerBuilder.java
Method: create
Line: 132 - com/opensymphony/xwork2/inject/ContainerBuilder.java:132:-1
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:493)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:202)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:177)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:468)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:234)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:132)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getInstance(ContainerImpl.java:514)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getInstance(ContainerImpl.java:524)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$9.call(ContainerImpl.java:555)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:584)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getInstance(ContainerImpl.java:553)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:257)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:502)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:539)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:593)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:537)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:301)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:438)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:499)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:132)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:469)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:299)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:502)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:539)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:593)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:537)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:301)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:438)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:499)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:132)
<continued in next message>
<continued from previous message>
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:469)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:299)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:502)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:539)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:593)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:537)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:301)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:438)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:499)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:132)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:469)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:299)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:502)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:539)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:593)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:537)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:301)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:438)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:499)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-1abb8d4ab73425c9(Request.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:299)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:438)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:499)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:539)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:593)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:537)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:469)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:299)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:438)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:499)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:539)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:593)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:537)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:469)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:299)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:438)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:499)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:539)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:593)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:537)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:469)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:299)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:438)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:499)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:539)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:593)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:537)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getInstance(ContainerImpl.java:514)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getInstance(ContainerImpl.java:524)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$9.call(ContainerImpl.java:555)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:584)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getInstance(ContainerImpl.java:553)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:257)
<continued in next message>
<continued from previous message>
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: Cannot load excluded class: java.lang.Shutdown - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setExcludedClasses(OgnlUtil.java:106)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.Shutdown
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-1abb8d4ab73425c9(Request.java)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:136)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setExcludedClasses(OgnlUtil.java:104)
    ... 76 more

Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException - Class: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4
File: ContainerBuilder.java
Method: create
Line: 132 - com/opensymphony/xwork2/inject/ContainerBuilder.java:132:-1
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:493)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:202)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:177)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:468)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:234)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:132)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getInstance(ContainerImpl.java:514)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getInstance(ContainerImpl.java:524)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$9.call(ContainerImpl.java:555)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:584)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getInstance(ContainerImpl.java:553)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:257)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:502)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:539)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:593)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:537)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:301)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:438)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:499)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:132)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:469)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:299)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:502)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:539)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:593)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:537)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:301)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:438)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:499)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:132)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:469)
    at com.opensymphony...(length 18310)
```

Answer (score 0):

The full stracktrace is:

```
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@1e1180b{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~appname/1.388915515680551489}
      java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException - Class: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4
      File: ContainerBuilder.java
      Method: create
      Line: 132 - com/opensymphony/xwork2/inject/ContainerBuilder.java:132:-1
...
blablabla, blablabla
....
      Caused by: Cannot load excluded class: java.lang.Shutdown - [unknown location]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setExcludedClasses(OgnlUtil.java:106)
        ... 76 more
      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.Shutdown
        at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-f55903b9ff93528e(Request.java)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:140)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setExcludedClasses(OgnlUtil.java:104)
```

The problem is that the OgnlUtil.setExcludedClasses (above struts v2.3.16) throws an ClassNotFoundException in the Google App Engine enviroment. If you remove the java.lang.Shutdown from the value of "struts.excludedClasses" constant (in the struts-default.xml) this error disappear. But you don't need to modify the struts2-core.jar, you can redefine it in your application struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.excludedClasses"
value="
java.lang.Object,
java.lang.Runtime,
java.lang.System,
java.lang.Class,
java.lang.ClassLoader,
```

<s>java.lang.Shutdown</s>,

```
ognl.OgnlContext,
ognl.MemberAccess,
ognl.ClassResolver,
ognl.TypeConverter,
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext"/>
```